# How do i export WEBSQL to excel?

Tags: jquery, excel

I have a code here.
How can i export the data from websql to excel even if and especially if we close the browser?
And please help me with the modal. It's not working.

Thanks to who will answer.

I have a code here.
How can i export the data from websql to excel even if and especially if we close the browser?
And please help me with the modal. It's not working.

Thanks to who will answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 

<html>  
   <head> 
    <title>SuperNotes v.2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/fontawesome.min.css"/>

  <script type = "text/javascript"> 

         var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024); 
         var msg; 

         db.transaction(function (tx) { 
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NAME (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, usdomain,agent)'); 
         })
         function load() {
         db.transaction(function (tx) { 
            loadagain();
         });
         }
         function insert() {
            var i;
            var usdomain = $('#usdomaintxt').val();
            var agent = $('#agenttxt').val();
             db.transaction(function (tx) {     
             tx.executeSql('insert into NAME(usdomain, agent) values("' + usdomain + '", "' + agent + '")');  
            loadagain();

        })
         }
         function showupdatediv(id) {
            $('#insertdiv').css('display', 'none');
            $('#updatediv').css('display', 'block');
            $('#idupdate').val(id);
            db.transaction(function (tx) { 
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE id=?',[id], function (tx, results) { 
               var len = results.rows.length, i;
               for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 

                  $('#usdomainupdate').val(results.rows.item(i).usdomain);
                  $('#agentupdate').val(results.rows.item(i).agent); 
               } 
            }, null);
        })
         }
         function update() {
            var id = $('#idupdate').val();
            var usdomain = $('#usdomainupdate').val();
            var agent = $('#agentupdate').val();
             db.transaction(function (tx) {     
             tx.executeSql('UPDATE NAME SET usdomain=?, agent=? WHERE id=?', [usdomain, agent, id]);
             $('#insertdiv').css('display', 'block');
            $('#updatediv').css('display', 'none');
            loadagain();
        })
         } 


         function loadagain() {
            db.transaction(function (tx) {   
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM NAME', [], function (tx, results) { 
               var len = results.rows.length, i;
               document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  "";
               for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
                  msg = "<tr><td>" + results.rows.item(i).id + "</td><td>" + results.rows.item(i).usdomain + "</td><td>"+ results.rows.item(i).agent +"</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger mr-1' id='"+ results.rows.item(i).id +"' onclick='deleteNote(db, this.id)'><i class='fa fa-trash-alt'></i></button><button class='btn btn-warning' id='"+ results.rows.item(i).id +"' onclick='showupdatediv(this.id);'>Edit <i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button></td></tr>"; 
                  document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg; 
               } 

               msg1 = "<BR><p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>"; 
               document.querySelector('#rows').innerHTML =  msg1;
            }, null);
         })
         }
         function deleteNote(db, id) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('delete from NAME where id=?', [id]);
        loadagain();
        });
    }


      </script> 


   </head> 
   <body onload="load();">
  <div class="container">

     <div id="insertdiv" class="row m-2">
      <label for="usdomaintext">US Domain: </label>
      <input class="m-1" type="text" id="usdomaintxt">
       <label for="agenttext">Name: </label>
      <input class="m-1" type="text" id="agenttxt">
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="insert();">INSERT<i class="fa fa-hand-middle-finger"></i></button>
     </div>
     <p id="rows">Found rows:</p>

     <div class=" table" style="overflow: auto; height: 600px; width: 500px">
        <center>
      <table id="nametbl" class="table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>USDOMAIN</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody id = "status" name = "status"></tbody> 
      </table>
      </center>
     </div>

      <div id="updatediv" style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" id="idupdate" value="">
        <label for="usdomainupdate">US Domain: </label>
      <input class="m-1" type="text" id="usdomainupdate" value="">
       <label for="agentupdate">Name: </label>
      <input class="m-1" type="text" id="agentupdate" value="">
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="update();">Update</button>
      </div>


 </div>



<!--Open Modal -->
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="agentmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer i think.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 

<html>  
   <head> 
    <title>SuperNotes v.2</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .modal, .modal-lg {
         height: 400px;
         width: 700px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script type = "text/javascript"> 

         var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024); 
         var msg; 

         db.transaction(function (tx) { 
            tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS NAME (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, usdomain,agent)'); 
         })
         function load() {
         db.transaction(function (tx) { 
            loadagain();
         });
         }
         function insert() {
            var i;
            var usdomain = $('#usdomaintxt').val();
            var agent = $('#agenttxt').val();
             db.transaction(function (tx) {     
             tx.executeSql('insert into NAME(usdomain, agent) values("' + usdomain + '", "' + agent + '")');  
            loadagain();

        })
         }
         function showupdatediv(id) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#updatemodal").modal();
   $("#agentmodal").modal('hide');
});
            $('#idupdate').val(id);
            db.transaction(function (tx) { 
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE id=?',[id], function (tx, results) { 
               var len = results.rows.length, i;
               for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 

                  $('#usdomainupdate').val(results.rows.item(i).usdomain);
                  $('#agentupdate').val(results.rows.item(i).agent); 
               } 
            }, null);
        })
         }
         function update() {
            var id = $('#idupdate').val();
            var usdomain = $('#usdomainupdate').val();
            var agent = $('#agentupdate').val();
             db.transaction(function (tx) {     
             tx.executeSql('UPDATE NAME SET usdomain=?, agent=? WHERE id=?', [usdomain, agent, id]);
            $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#updatemodal").modal('hide');
   $("#agentmodal").modal();
});
            loadagain();
        })
         } 


         function loadagain() {
            db.transaction(function (tx) {   
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM NAME', [], function (tx, results) { 
               var len = results.rows.length, i;
               document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  "";
               for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
                  msg = "<tr><td>" + results.rows.item(i).id + "</td><td>" + results.rows.item(i).usdomain + "</td><td>"+ results.rows.item(i).agent +"</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger mr-1' id='"+ results.rows.item(i).id +"' onclick='deleteNote(db, this.id)'><i class='fa fa-trash-alt'></i></button><button class='btn btn-warning' id='"+ results.rows.item(i).id +"' onclick='showupdatediv(this.id);'>Edit <i class='fa fa-edit'></i></button></td></tr>"; 
                  document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg; 
               } 

               msg1 = "<BR><p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>"; 
               document.querySelector('#rows').innerHTML =  msg1;
            }, null);
         })
         }
         function deleteNote(db, id) {
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('delete from NAME where id=?', [id]);
        loadagain();
        });
    }

        load();
      </script> 


   </head> 
   <body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agentmodal">
  Agent Management
</button>






<!-- Agent Modal -->

  <div class="modal fade right" id="agentmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalPreviewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <center>
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalPreviewLabel">Agent User Management</h5>
        </center>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Content Here -->
        <div class="card card-primary">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <div class="container">

     <div id="insertdiv" class="row m-2">
      <label for="usdomaintext">US Domain: </label>
      <input class="m-1" type="text" id="usdomaintxt">
       <label for="agenttext">Name: </label>
      <input class="m-1" type="text" id="agenttxt">
      <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="insert();">INSERT<i class="fa fa-hand-middle-finger"></i></button>
     </div>
     <p id="rows">Found rows:</p>

     <div class=" table" style="overflow: auto; height: 400px;">
      <center>
      <table id="nametbl" class="table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>USDOMAIN</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
      <tbody id = "status" name = "status"></tbody> 
      </table>
      </center>
     </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

 </div>
      <!-- Content End -->
      </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<!-- Update Modal -->
<div class="modal fade right" id="updatemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalPreviewLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalPreviewLabel">Update</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="updatediv">
        <input type="hidden" id="idupdate" value="">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usdomainupdate">US Domain: </label>
      <input class="m-1" type="text" id="usdomainupdate" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
       <label for="agentupdate">Name:     </label>
      <input class="ml-4" type="text" id="agentupdate" value="">
       </div>

      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="update();">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->

   </body> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated it.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Super Notes</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<style>
body {
margin: 5px 0 0 0;
padding: 5px 30px;
background-color: white;
}
input {
width: 60%;
height: 7%;
font-size: 15px;
}

textarea {
width: 70%;
height: 20%;
font-size: 15px;
}
b {
font-size: 10px;
}
.btntog {
width: auto;
height: 5%;
white-space: normal; 
}
.form-group, .form-control {
width:95%;
padding:1px;
margin:1px;
}
.table ,.tr .td{
    border:1px solid black
}
.tbody {
    display:block;
    height:450px;
    overflow:auto;
}
#tableWrap tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #f2dce0;
}
.error {
    border-color: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: shake .1s linear;
    animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

@keyframes shake {
    0% { left: -5px; }
    100% { right: -5px; }
}
.thead, .tbody .tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;/* even columns width , fix width of table too*/
}
.thead {
    width: calc( 100% - 1em )/* scrollbar is average 1em/16px width, remove it from thead width */
}
.btn-toolbar {
     margin-left: 0px;
}
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The actual popup (appears on top) */
.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Popup arrow */
.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */
.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;} 
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div style="float:right;">
        <select class="form-control" id="theme" onchange="selectcolor()" style="width:100%;">
     <option value="theme">Theme</option>
    <option value="pink">Pink</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="orange">Orange</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="purple">Purple</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<div id="bgdiv" class="row" style="border:1px solid rgb(220,220,220); background-color:rgba(220,220,220,1); padding:10px; border-radius: 5px">
    <div class="container c-style" id="note">
        <center><h4>Super Notes</h4></center>

 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="form-group">
         <label for="aname">Agent's Name</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="aname" onchange="nameperm()">
     <option>Choose your Name</option>
        <option value="Jerome Altarejos">Jerome Altarejos</option>
        <option value="Prime Arat III">Prime Arat III</option>
        <option value="Nicole Maverick Albarracin">Nicole Maverick Albaraccin</option>
                <option value="Regine Caballero ">Regine Caballero</option>
                <option value="Hercy Calpito">Hercy Calpito</option>
                <option value="Sheila Mae Debuton">Sheila Debuton</option>
                <option value="Dennison Feliciano">Dennison Feliciano</option>
                <option value="Myla Fernandez">Myla Fernandez</option>
                <option value="Christian Garcia">Christian Garcia</option>
                <option value="Maribeth Garcia ">Maribeth Garcia</option>
                <option value="Remon Villamel Joyner ">Remon Joyner</option>
                <option value="Jeric  Macamay">Jeric Macamay</option>
                <option value="John Lester Matnog">John Lester Matnog</option>
                <option value="John Bernard Miranda">John Bernard Miranda</option>
                <option value="Jessie Alexander Morete ">Jessie Alexander Morete</option>
                <option value="Jhulia Star Pascua">Jhulia Star Pascua</option>
                <option value="Cyr Patrick Pulmano ">Cyr Patrick Pulmano</option>
                <option value="Michael Ramirez ">Michael Ramirez</option>
                <option value="Nirvana Ramos ">Nirvana Ramos</option>
                <option value="Walfredo Sanchez ">Walfredo Sanchez</option>
                <option value="Michelle Santos">Michelle Santos</option>
                <option value="Polimar Serran">Polimar Serran</option>
                <option value="Jessica Mae Velasquez">Jessica Mae Velasquez</option>
                <option value="Ludyvie Veligano">Ludyvie Veligano</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cbn">Call Time:</label>
    <input type="text" id="min" style="width:10%; height: 5%; border-radius:3px" value="0">:
   <input type="text" id="sec" style="width:10%; height: 5%; border-radius:3px" value="0">
</div>
</div> 
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <label for="rowcount"># of Calls:</label>
    <input type="text" id="rowcount" style="width:11%; height: 6%; border-radius:3px; font-size: 20px; text-align:center" value="0" disabled>

<label for="aht">AHT</label>
    <input type="text" id="aht" style="width:18%; height: 6%; border-radius:3px; font-size: 20px; text-align:center" value="000" disabled>

         <button type="button" id="nextcall" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addRow()" style="float:right">Next Call</button>
</div>
</div>
<hr>      
<form style="font-size:11px">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cname">Caller Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cname" placeholder="Enter Caller Name" onchange="casetempval()">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cbn">Phone No.</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cbn" placeholder="Enter Call Back Number" onchange="casetempval()">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
         <label for="typeofcall">Type of Call</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="typeofcall" onchange="casetempval()">
    <option>Enter Type of Call</option>

        <option value="Authorization Status Check">Authorization Status Check</option>
        <option value="Authorization Update">Authorization Update</option>
        <option value="Initial Authorization/Case Created">Initial Authorization/Case Created</option>
    <option value="Precertification Check">Precertification Check</option>
    <option value="Misroute">Misroute</option>
    <option value="Initiate Appeals">Initiate Appeals</option>
    <option value="Initiate Peer To Peer">Initiate Peer To Peer</option>
    <option value="General Inquiry">General Inquiry</option>
    <option value="Disconnected Call/Dropped Call">Disconnected Call/Dropped Call</option>
    <option value="Expedite Request">Expedite Request
</option>
      </select>
 </div>
   <hr>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cbn">Provider NPI</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="provnpi" placeholder="Enter Provider NPI" onchange="casetempval()">
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="cbn">Facility NPI #</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="facinpi" placeholder="Enter Facility NPI " onchange="casetempval()">
  </div>
<hr>

<div class="form-group" id="memdiv">


    <label for="cbn">Member ID #</label>
<select class="form-control" id="multiplemem" onchange="casetempval()" style="width:21%; float:right; margin-right:15px">
        <option value="no">no</option>
        <option value="yes">yes</option>

</select>
<span style="float:right; margin-right:15px">Multiple Member?</span>

   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="memid" placeholder="Enter Member ID No." onchange="casetempval()">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
         <label for="region">Contracting Region</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="region" onchange="casetempval()">
    <option>Region</option>
        <option value="NE Local">NE Local</option>
    <option value="NY Local">NY Local</option>
    <option value="Other Regions">Other Regions</option>
    <option value="N/A">N/A</option>
      </select>
  </div>


</div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">


<div class="form-group">
         <label for="placeofservice">Place of Service</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="placeofservice" onchange="casetempval()">
    <option>Enter Place of Service</option>

        <option value="Office">OFFICE</option>
        <option value="Ambulatory">AMBULATORY </option>
        <option value="Outpatient Hospital">OP HOSP</option>
    <option value="Inpatient Hospital">IP HOSP</option>
    <option value="HOME">HOME</option>
      </select>
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
         <label for="typeofservice">Type of Service</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="typeofservice" onchange="casetempval()">
    <option>Enter Type of Service</option>

        <option value="Elective">Elective</option>
        <option value="Emergency">Emergency</option>
        <option value="Urgent">Urgent</option>
    <option value="Maternity">Maternity</option>
    <option value="NICU">NICU</option>
      </select>
  </div>
<hr>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cpt">CPT</label><select class="form-control" id="multiplecode" onchange="casetempval()" style="width:21%; float:right; margin-right:15px">
        <option value="no">no</option>
        <option value="yes">yes</option>

</select>
<span style="float:right; margin-right:15px">Multiple Code?</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpt" placeholder="Enter CPT Codes" onchange="casetempval()">
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="icd">ICD 10</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ICD" placeholder="Enter Dx Codes" onchange="casetempval()">
  </div> 
<hr>

<div class="form-group" id="tempnotedivne" style="display:none">
         <label for="tempnotene">Template Note NE</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="tempnotene" onchange="casetempval()">
    <option>Enter Template Note</option>

        <option value="Precert Created">Precert Created</option>
        <option value="Case Status Check – No Changes to Case">Case Status Check – No Changes to Case</option>
        <option value="Case Update / Extension Request">Case Update / Extension Request </option>
    <option value="No Review Required">No Review Required</option>
    <option value="Inpatient Surgery/Outpatient Surgery/DME">Inpatient Surgery/Outpatient Surgery/DME</option>
    <option value="ER Cases">ER Cases</option>
    <option value="Genetic Testing">Genetic Testing</option>
      </select>
 </div>
<div class="form-group" id="tempnotedivny" style="display:none">
         <label for="tempnoteny">Template Note NY</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="tempnoteny" onchange="casetempval()">
    <option>Enter Template Note NY</option>

        <option value="ER Cases">ER Cases</option>
        <option value="All Other Inpatient (IP) and Outpatient (OP) Cases">All Other Inpatient (IP) and Outpatient (OP) Cases</option>
    <option value="Case Status Check – No Changes to Case">Case Status Check – No Changes to Case</option>
    <option value="No Review Required">No Review Required</option>
    <option value="No Benefit">No Benefit</option>
    <option value="Coverage Terminated">Coverage Terminated</option>
    <option value="Pre-D Suggested and Caller Declines">Pre-D Suggested and Caller Declines</option>
    <option value="Pre-Note and Auto Approval">Pre-Note and Auto Approval</option>
    <option value="Changes to a Case">Changes to a Case</option>
    <option value="Non-Urgent to Urgent">Non-Urgent to Urgent</option>
      </select>
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
         <label for="transfer">Transfer</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="transfer" onchange="casetempval()">
    <option>Enter Transfer</option>
    <option value="AIM">AIM: 877-430-2288
</option>
    <option value="Appeals">Appeals: 918006345605 *2
</option>
    <option value="Behavioral">BH: 918006263643
</option>
    <option value="Blue Card">Blue Card: 800-810-2583</option>
    <option value="Federal Employee Program">Federal Employee Program: 918008602156</option>
    <option value="Member Services">Member Services</option>
    <option value="National Account">National Account</option>
    <option value="NE Onshore">NE Onshore: 8554784369</option>
    <option value="Nurse">Nurse</option>
        <option value="NY Onshore">NY Onshore: 866-6040-936
</option>
    <option value="NY Onshore - Abroad Excluded">NY Onshore - Abroad Excluded</option>
    <option value="NY Onshore - Denied Cases">NY Onshore - Denied Cases</option>
    <option value="NY Onshore - FI HMO/HPOS">NY Onshore - FI HMO/HPOS</option>
    <option value="Peer to Peer">Peer to Peer</option>
    <option value="Provider Services">Provider Services</option>
    <option value="Specialty Drug">Specialty Drug: 833-293-0659</option>
    <option value="State of CT">State of CT: 800-922-2232</option>
    <option value="Sup Call">Sup Call</option>
    <option value="Total Transfer">Total Transfer</option>
    <option value="TPA">TPA</option>
    <option value="Others">Others(Please Specify)</option>
      </select>
 </div>

 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="form-group">
         <label for="clinicals">Clinicals</label>
     <select class="form-control" id="clinicals" onchange="casetempval()">
    <option>Clinical Fax Number</option>
<option value="NY Clinical">NY Clinical: 877-236-5159

</option>
        <option value="CT OP Clinical">CT OP Clinical: 877-539-3851

</option>
        <option value="ME OP Clinical">ME OP Clinical: 877-539-3855 or 877-539-3856

</option>
        <option value="NH OP Clinical">NH OP Clinical: 877-539-3860 or 877-539-9588

</option>
    <option value="CT IP Clinical">CT IP Clinical: Concurrent(877-549-3987) / Future(877-539-3851)</option>
    <option value="ME IP Clinical">ME IP Clinical: Concurrent(877-539-9589) / Future(877-539-3855)</option>
    <option value="NH IP Clinical">NH IP Clinical: Concurrent(800-281-1049) / Future( 877-539-3860 or 877-539-9588)
</option>
      </select>
 </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="cbn">Work ID/Case No.</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="caseno" placeholder="Enter Case No./ Work ID" onchange="casetempval()">
  </div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Additional Note:</label><br>
    <textarea id="addnote" Placeholder="Enter your notes here" style="width: 95%" onchange="casetempval()"></textarea>
  </div> 

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Case Template:</label><br>
    <textarea id="casetemp" disabled style="width: 95%"></textarea>
  </div> 

 </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="clearall" class="btn btn-danger" style="float:right; margin-left:5px;" onclick="reset()">Clear</button>
  <button type="button" id="trackdivbtn" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="tracktable()" style="float:right; margin-left:5px;">Table Tracker</button>
<button type="button" id="historydivbtn" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="historytable()" style="float:right">History</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="send()" style="float:left">Send Email</button>
</form>
</div>
<div id="historydiv" style="display:none; padding:5px">
<button id="btnexporthistory" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right; margin:5px;" onclick="exportTableToExcel1()">Export</button>

<div id="tableWrapHistory" style="display:block; overflow-x: auto;" class="table">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Name</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Phone Number</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Provider NPI</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Facility NPI</th>
<th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Member ID #</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Region</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Place of Service</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Type of Service</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">CPT</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">DX</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Type of Call</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black">Transfer</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Clinicals</th>
<th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Multiple Member/Code</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Work ID/Case Number</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 300px; border: 1px solid black">Remarks</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; border: 1px solid black">Min</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; border: 1px solid black">Sec</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableWrapBodyHistory">

    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    </div>


<div id="trackdiv" style="display:none; padding:5px">
<button id="btnexport" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right; margin:5px;" onclick="exportTableToExcel()">Export</button>

<div id="tableWrap" style="display:block" class="tally table">
    <table id="tabletracker" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Name</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Type of Call</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black">Transfer</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black">Region</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Work ID/Case Number</th>
        <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black">Multiple Member/Code</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; width: 300px; border: 1px solid black">Remarks</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; border: 1px solid black">Min</th>
    <th style="background-color:#5f8fc2; color: white; border: 1px solid black">Sec</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableWrapBody">

    </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    </div>
<!-- jQuery library -->

<footer><center><span style="color: rgb(220,220,220); font-size:16px"><div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">About the Tool
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">&#9400;Jerome Altarejos</span>
</div></span><center></footer>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/4.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(function(){exportTableToExcel();},3600000);
function send() {
window.open('mailto:Christian.Garcia2@anthem.com');
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function nameperm() {
$("#aname").attr("disabled", true);
document.getElementById("aname").style.backgroundColor="";
}
function exportTableToExcel(){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableHTML = encodeURIComponent($('#tableWrap').html());
    var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    if (document.getElementById("aname").value != "Choose your Name") {
    var aname = document.getElementById("aname").value + "-Call Tracker-" + today;
}
if (document.getElementById("aname").value == "Choose your Name") {
    var aname = "Call Tracker-" + today;
}
    // Specify file name
    filename = aname?aname+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();

    }
}
function exportTableToExcel1(){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableHTML = encodeURIComponent($('#tableWrapHistory').html());
    var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    if (document.getElementById("aname").value != "Choose your Name") {
    var aname = document.getElementById("aname").value + "-History-" + today;
}
if (document.getElementById("aname").value == "Choose your Name") {
    var aname = "History-" + today;
}
    // Specify file name
    filename = aname?aname+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what you have updated or fixed with the code, so the OP and future viewers can understand the issue and the resolution.